# O tipo 'SC_d5836a92a0634aa19f5047b44a44f837.ResultApi' não é suportado para desserialização de uma matriz

Tags: c#

Fala Pessoal,
Estou tomando o seguinte erro: .ResultApi' não é suportado para desserialização de uma matriz.

O meu json vem assim:

```
    [
{
    "tipoConta": "DEP",
    "descricaoTipoConta": "Conta teste",
    "saldoDisponivel": 0.0,
    "saldoBloqueado": 0.0,
    "saldoProjetado": 0.0,
    "saldoD1": 0.0,
    "saldoD2": 0.0,
    "saldoD3": 0.0,
    "saldoAposD3": 0.0,
    "saldoTotal": 94.93,
    "dataD0": "2021-10-19T00:00:00",
    "dataD1": "2021-10-20T00:00:00",
    "dataD2": "2021-10-21T00:00:00",
    "dataD3": "2021-10-22T00:00:00",
    "dataAposD3": "2021-10-25T00:00:00",
    "cdCliente": xxxx
}
```

]

Criei as classes:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:0000/v1/posicao-financeiro/xxxx");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    string ApiUrl = string.Format("http://0.0.0.0:0000/v1/posicao-financeiro/xxxx");

    var response = client.GetAsync(ApiUrl).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var data = serializer.Deserialize<ResultApi>(result);



        Output0Buffer.tipoConta = data.tipoConta;
        Output0Buffer.descricaoTipoConta = data.descricaoTipoConta;
        Output0Buffer.saldoDisponivel = data.saldoDisponivel;
        Output0Buffer.saldoBloqueado = data.saldoBloqueado;
        Output0Buffer.saldoProjetado = data.saldoProjetado;
        Output0Buffer.saldoD1 = data.saldoD1;
        Output0Buffer.saldoD2 = data.saldoD2;
        Output0Buffer.saldoD3 = data.saldoD3;
        Output0Buffer.saldoTotal = data.saldoTotal;
        Output0Buffer.dataD0 = data.dataD0;
        Output0Buffer.dataD1 = data.dataD1;
        Output0Buffer.dataD2 = data.dataD2;
        Output0Buffer.dataD3 = data.dataD3;
        Output0Buffer.DataAposD3 = data.dataAposD3;
        Output0Buffer.codCliente = data.cdCliente;






    }

}

}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SC_d5836a92a0634aa19f5047b44a44f837
{
    public class ResultApi 
    {
        public  string tipoConta { get; set; }
        public string descricaoTipoConta { get; set; }
        public decimal saldoDisponivel { get; set; }

        public decimal saldoBloqueado { get; set; }
        public decimal saldoProjetado { get; set; }
        public decimal saldoD1 { get; set; }
        public decimal saldoD2 { get; set; }
        public decimal saldoD3 { get; set; }
        public string saldoAposD3 { get; set; }

        public decimal saldoTotal { get; set; }

        public DateTime dataD0 { get; set; }

        public DateTime dataD1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime dataD2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime dataD3 { get; set; }
        public DateTime dataAposD3 { get; set; }
        public string cdCliente { get; set; }

    }


}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SC_d5836a92a0634aa19f5047b44a44f837
{
   public class GenericResponse
    {
        public ResultApi[] Listdata { get; set; }

    }
    public class ResultGen
    {
        public GenericResponse Result { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Sabem o que pode estar errado? Sou da área de dados e preciso fazer uma ingestão usando o Integration, porém não conheço muito C#.

Comment: Já tentou usar o tipo `GenericResponse` para desserializar?

Comment: Não entendi, como seria?

Comment: Eu não entendo de C#, mas seria algo assim: `var data = serializer.Deserialize<GenericResponse>(result);`

Comment: Tentei, mas nao funcionou. :(

Answer (score -1):

Você só precisa desserializar para uma coleção de algum tipo - por exemplo, um array. Afinal, o seu JSON faz representar um array, e não um único item. Exemplo curto, mas completo:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var people = serializer.Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(people[0].Name); // ABC
    }
}
```